# Normal range of Free T4: 0.9 - 1.8 ng/dL or 0.6 - 1.4 ng/dL?

Tags: thyroid, hyperthyroid, hypothyroid

When my wife did her blood test a few years ago, the normal range for the free T4 was given as 0.9 - 1.8 ng/dL. Her score was 1.75.

Now my daughter (21) just did the test, the range for T4 was given as 0.6 - 1.4 ng/dL. Her score is 1.78 and is out of range.
I have found on the internet that the range is about 0.5 - 1.8 ng/dL. I am not sure where this 0.6 - 1.4 comes from. Is the range based on age?

note: the TSH for both of them was < 0.01.

Comment: Lab value ranges can vary from one lab to another.

Comment: Does that mean labs can define their own ranges?

Comment: Not really. It's more like calibrating an instrument. It just means that results will vary somewhat depending on the lab techniques used, reagents, etc, so each lab will determine the reference range for _their_ lab. Their numbers may differ slightly, but if you're out of range on one lab's test and you do that test using another lab, they should both agree you're out of range in the same direction and proportion. Maybe someone who knows more about this will write an answer.

Comment: "like calibrating an instrument." - this makes sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: Being a male results will vary but I had testorone levels off the scale also when I gained weight it came back down.